# Может ли (теоретически) журналист быть бывшим?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> Пять с лишним лет назад вел рубрику «Из дальних странствий» в местной
>   газете. Газета перестала существовать, с другими СМИ меня ничего не
>   связывает. Ныне пишу книги и брошюры (жанр – путевые заметки,
>   публицистика), на обложках которых указываю, что я – бывший журналист,
>   или «в прошлом – журналист».

Грамотно ли это?

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, может — пока человек жив, не возвращается к журналистике и занимается чем-то другим. Например, писатель Хемингуэй в своём прошлом был журналистом, при жизни (в поздние годы) его вполне можно было называть "бывшим журналистом". Не бывает только бывших президентов США (при ссылке — президент + имя), бывших чемпионов мира по шахматам (порядковый номер + чемпион) и бывших чемпионов-олимпийцев (чемпион + год).

Comment: @ Alex_ander, только президентов США?

Comment: Про других не слышал, не могу полностью исключить.